# Can't get custom slot working in PyQT4 with QT4 designer

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I am new to PyQT4.

After some tuts I decided to make a simple GUI in which I will enter text in first line and on clicking of Reverse button ,it will show reversed string on second line.

I made a custom slot for this,by defining the function in my class.But when I click reverse nothing happens. I have used in-bilt slots for Clear button and Exit button in my GUI and they are working perfectly.

If someone can just clarify this custom slot problem it would help me advance further.

Thanks in advance.

Here's a photo of my GUI

http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/7131/diall.png

## Stringreverse.py Final File

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

    

from stringreverse_ui import Ui_Dialog

    class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui=Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton_3,QtCore.SIGNAL("Click()"), self.reverse)



    def reverse(self):
        s=self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(s[::-1])
    
    
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()")` instead of `QtCore.SIGNAL("Click()")`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Francis. I tried it out. But again it doesn't affect any change. Kind of frustrating .